# Merge one website into another website on same domain in Magento1.9.2.4 [Multiwebsite]

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website

I have Multi-website domain , which has 4 website with one store in each.

Likewise Site Structure-

```
Domain : example.com

Website                Store

example.com             UK         
example.com/fr          FR
outlet.example.com      UK
outlet.example.com/fr   FR
```

Now I want to merge website-

> `outlet.example.com (UK)` into `example.com (UK)`

and

> `outlet.example.com/fr (FR)` into `example.com (UK)`.

So -

1. Which Entities among below,I need to move and HOW can I move each of
   them  ?

   - customer,
   - orders,
   - promotions,
   - categories,
   - products,
   - newsletter subscribers etc.
2. What changes it would require at backend or at code level as well ?